# Getting the following Error Message : 'Patient' object has no attribute 'get__firstName'

Tags: python

I am doing the following code for a Q in college on Patient Charges and keep getting the following error message when I debug.

> 'Patient' object has no attribute 'get__firstName'

I have set up the class and imported it and it seems to be working.

My Program looks like this:

```
import patient

def main():

    print('Please Enter the following Patient Details : ')

    firstName = input('First Name : ')

    middleName = input('Middle Name : ')

    lastName = input('Last Name : ')

    address = input('Street Address : ')

    city = input('City : ')

    zipCode = input('Zip Code : ')

    phone_num = input('Phone Number : ')

    emergency_contact_name = input('Name of Emergency Contact : ')

    emergency_number = input('Emergency Contact Number : ')



    details = patient.Patient(firstName, middleName, lastName, address, city, zipCode, phone_num, emergency_contact_name, emergency_number)



    print('Here is the information you have entered: ')

    print()

    print('----------------')

    print('First Name :', details.get__firstName())

    print('Middle Name : ', details.get__middleName())

    print('Last Name : ', details.get__lastName())

    print('Street Address : ', details.get__address())

    print('City : ', details.get__city())

    print('Zip Code : ', details.get__zipCode())

    print('Phone Number : ', details.get__phone_num())

    print('Emergency Contact Name : ', details.get__emergency_contact_name())

    print('Emergency Contact Number : ', details.get__emergency_number())


    print()

main()
```

---

This is my class:

```
class Patient:
    
    def __init__(self, firstName, middleName, lastName, address, city, zipCode, 
                 phone_num, emergency_contact_name, emergency_number):
        
        self.__firstName = firstName

        self.__middleName = middleName

        self.__lastName = lastName

        self.__address = address

        self.__city = city

        self.__zipCode = zipCode

        self.__phone_num = phone_num

        self.__emergency_contact_name = emergency_contact_name

        self.__emergency_number = emergency_number

    # set methods

    def set_firstName(self, firstName):

        self.firstName = firstName

    def set_middleName(self, middleName):

        self.middleName = middleName

    def set_lastName(self, lastName):

        self.lastName = lastName

    def set_address(self, address):

        self.address = address

    def set_city(self, city):

        self.city = city

    def set_zipCode(self, zipCode):

        self.zipCode = zipCode

    def set_phone_num(self, phone_num):

        self.phone_num = phone_num

    def set_emergency_contact_name(self, emergency_contact_name):

        self.emergency_contact_name = emergency_contact_name

    def set_emergency_number(self, emergency_number):

        self.emergency_number = emergency_number

    # get methods

    def get_firstName(self):

        return self.__firstName

    def get_middleName(self):

        return self.__middleName

    def get_lastName(self):

        return self.__lastName

    def get_address(self):

        return self.__address

    def get_city(self):

        return self.__city

    def get_zipCode(self):

        return self.__zipCode

    def get_phone_num(self):

        return self.__phone_num

    def get_emergency_contact_name(self):

        return self.__emergency_contact_name

    def get_emergency_number(self):

        return self.__emergency_number
```

Comment: For one thing, `"get__firstName" != "get_firstName"`. But for another that's absolutely **not** how you write this in Python - don't write getters and setters, just access the attribute then introduce a `@property` if it actually becomes necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`get_firstName` is written with one `_` in the class and with 2 when you call it.

Anyway, in Python, you normally don't use setters and getters like this. Take a look at [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/getter-and-setter-in-python/) for more info.